# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

`@WebMethod(operationName = "SearchOR")`

```
  public  SearchOR getSearchOR (@WebParam(name = "comp")
  String comp, @WebParam(name = "name")
 String name) {
            //TODO write your implementation code here:
     SearchOR ack = null;

    try{
     String simpleProc = "{ call getuser_info_or(?,?)}";
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(simpleProc);
        cs.setString(1, comp);
        cs.setString(2, name);
        **ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();**


      while (rs.next()) {

           ve.add(rs.getString(1));
           ve.add(rs.getString(2));

        }}catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    return ack;
}
```

I am getting error at portion i have made bold.It is pointing to that location.My Query is
here:

`DELIMITER $$`

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS` `` .`getuser_info_or ``$$
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`

`CREATE PROCEDURE` `.`getuser_info_or``

`(`
`IN comp VARCHAR(100),`
`IN name VARCHAR(100),`
`OUT Login VARCHAR(100),`
`OUT email VARCHAR(100)`
`)`

`BEGIN`
`SELECT sLogin, sEmail`
`INTO Login, email`
`FROM ad_user`
`WHERE company = comp OR sName=name;`
`END $$`

`# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`

`DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is your call does not match the method definition. In your definition you have two parameters: IN comp, IN name, **OUT Login, OUT email**. So your call should be:

```
String simpleProc = "{ call getuser_info_or(?, ?, ?, ?)}";
```

And from the javadocs:

> If used, the result parameter must be
>   registered as an OUT parameter.

So you would need to add those registrations:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
```

The stored procedure as defined does not create a resultset for the retrieved data, but rather places it in the out parameters. To fetch them you will need to access them via the callable statement:

```
String login = cs.getString(3);
String email = cs.getString(4);
```

Comment: Thanks .Thanks for ur response ... Now gwtting this error ..any idea about it..


java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
        at 

com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:6450)
        at WS.TestDB.getSearchAnd(TestDB.java:85)
        at WS.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:98)

Comment: It is because your procedure does not create a resultset. You need to get the values from the statement. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi very thanks jessup will like to ask some more doubts .If possible can u share ur mail id or IM like that something so it would be more helpful to me.Have lot of doubt...:-(